# Couenne solver for MINLPs provides optimal solution status, but results are far from expected optimal

Tags: python, pyomo, nonlinear-optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I am currently working on the optimization solution for some industry tasks. I currently use Pyomo and usually write algorithms in Spyder. Due to certain limitations, I have to do it on Windows x64 PCs. I am struggling with Couenne solver. I was able to install the package, my goal was to check how it works. But when I tried to test it on a mixed-integer nonlinear problem with multiply variables and constraints, I got totally different output rather than in the provided example.

For the test I've found one non-linear mixed-integer problem solution tutorial, that is shown here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=80M-x1ksiNs&list=PUYeCtS8JUZATtqWsZNKgjVg&index=18

Script (on video) and reference output of the solution:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dl_YLkiRxoc&list=PUYeCtS8JUZATtqWsZNKgjVg&index=22

The problem code was copied from provided instructions:
(Maybe I copied it wrong, but I checked it few times)

```
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory
import numpy as np

# Problem parameters

input_torque = 1400.53333333 

fwd_ratio=4.3
rev_ratio=9.1

# Initial diameter guess value
D_guess=np.array([4.5,11.5,6.0,10.0,4.5,2.5,2.25,9.0])
# Initial guess of the teeth number
N_guess=np.array([18,46,24,40,18,20,18,72])
# Initial pitch diameter guess
P_guess =np.array([4,5,18])
# Initial face width
b_guess=np.array([1,1,1])
# Initial central distance guess
C_guess= 5
# Index for number of teeth and the diameter 
idx=np.arange(0,8)
# Index for pitch and face width
idx1=np.arange(0,3)

D_dict={}
N_dict={}
P_dict={}
b_dict={}


for i in idx:
    D_dict[i]=D_guess[i]
    N_dict[i]=N_guess[i]
    
for i in idx1:
    P_dict[i]=P_guess[i]
    b_dict[i]=b_guess[i]

# Creating the model object. ConcreteModel instance is appropriate 
# as all of the data needed to complete the model is avaiable.
model = ConcreteModel()

# Declare the model variables
# Using Index to access individual gear diameter, bound is the domain
model.D = Var([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],initialize=D_dict, within=PositiveReals, bounds=(1.5,30))
model.N = Var([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],initialize=N_dict, within=PositiveIntegers, bounds=(18,300))
model.P = Var([1,2,3],initialize=P_dict, within=PositiveIntegers, bounds=(4,80))
model.b = Var([1,2,3],initialize=b_dict, within=PositiveReals)
model.C = Var(initialize=C_guess, within=PositiveReals)

# Declare the objective function 
# Represent the total error
def obj_fun(model):
    # Defining the residuals
    # Error between the model (via diameter) and goal ratio
    R1=abs((model.D[2]/model.D[1])*(model.D[4]/model.D[3])-fwd_ratio)
    R2=abs((model.D[2]/model.D[5])*(model.D[7]/model.D[6])*(model.D[8]/model.D[7])-rev_ratio)
    # Error between the model (via number of teeth) and goal ratio
    R3=abs((model.N[2]/model.N[1])*(model.N[4]/model.N[3])-fwd_ratio)
    R4=abs((model.N[2]/model.N[5])*(model.N[7]/model.N[6])*(model.N[8]/model.N[7])-rev_ratio)
    return R1+R2+R3+R4

# Declare constraints functions

# Diametral pitch constraints
def con_fun1(model):
    
    return model.N[1]/model.D[1] == model.P[1]

def con_fun2(model):
    
    return model.N[2]/model.D[2] == model.P[1]

def con_fun3(model):
    
    return model.N[3]/model.D[3] == model.P[2]

def con_fun4(model):
    
    return model.N[4]/model.D[4] == model.P[2]

def con_fun5(model):
    
    return model.N[5]/model.D[5] == model.P[1]

def con_fun6(model):
    
    return model.N[6]/model.D[6] == model.P[3]

def con_fun7(model):
    
    return model.N[7]/model.D[7] == model.P[3]

def con_fun8(model):
    
    return model.N[8]/model.D[8] == model.P[3]

# Central Distance constraints 

def con_fun9(model):
    
    return (model.D[1]+model.D[2])/2 == model.C

def con_fun10(model):
    
    return (model.D[3]+model.D[4])/2 == model.C

def con_fun11(model):
    
    return (model.D[5]+model.D[2])/2 == model.C

def con_fun12(model):
    
    return (model.D[6]+model.D[8])/2 + model.D[7] == model.C

# Declare the pitch-face width constraints

def con_fun13(model):
    
    return 9.0/model.P[1] <= model.b[1]

def con_fun14(model):
    
    return model.b[1] <= 14.0/model.P[1]

def con_fun15(model):
    
    return 9.0/model.P[2] <= model.b[2]

def con_fun16(model):
    
    return model.b[2] <= 14.0/model.P[2]

def con_fun17(model):
    
    return 9.0/model.P[3] <= model.b[3]

def con_fun18(model):
    
    return model.b[3] <= 14.0/model.P[3]

# Declare Gear Tooth Constraint
# Fundamentals of Machine Component Design (Simplified)

def con_fun19(model):
    
    d=model.D[1]
    n=model.N[1]
    p=model.P[1]
    b=model.b[1]
    
    ratio = 1.0
    
    Ft = (input_torque*ratio)/(d/2)
    
    pressure_angle = np.deg2rad(20)
    
    # J - Geometry factor
    
    J = 0.3
    
    # Kv - velocity factor
    
    Kv= 2.5
    
    # Km - mounting factor
    
    Km = 1.4 
    
    # Cg - gradient factor
    
    Cg = 0.85
    
    Bn = 388  # AISI 4140 Steel
    
    Kt = 1
    
    Sn = Bn/4
    
    Cl = 1.0
    
    Kr = 0.753
    
    Cs = 0.634
    
    Kms = 1.0 
    
    Ko = 1.0
    
    gear_stress = (((Ft*p)/(b*J))*Kv*Ko*Km)/1000
    
    gear_strength = Sn*Cl*Cg*Cs*Kr*Kt*Kms
    
    return gear_stress <= gear_strength

def con_fun20(model):
    
    d=model.D[2]
    n=model.N[2]
    p=model.P[1]
    b=model.b[1]
    
    ratio = model.D[2]/model.D[1]
    
    Ft = (input_torque*ratio)/(d/2)
    
    pressure_angle = np.deg2rad(20)
    
    # J - Geometry factor
    
    J = 0.3
    
    # Kv - velocity factor
    
    Kv= 2.5
    
    # Km - mounting factor
    
    Km = 1.4 
    
    # Cg - gradient factor
    
    Cg = 0.85
    
    Bn = 388  # AISI 4140 Steel
    
    Kt = 1
    
    Sn = Bn/4
    
    Cl = 1.0
    
    Kr = 0.753
    
    Cs = 0.634
    
    Kms = 1.0 
    
    Ko = 1.0
    
    gear_stress = (((Ft*p)/(b*J))*Kv*Ko*Km)/1000
    
    gear_strength = Sn*Cl*Cg*Cs*Kr*Kt*Kms
    
    return gear_stress <= gear_strength
    
def con_fun21(model):
    
    d=model.D[3]
    n=model.N[3]
    p=model.P[2]
    b=model.b[2]
    
    ratio = model.D[2]/model.D[1]
    
    Ft = (input_torque*ratio)/(d/2)
    
    pressure_angle = np.deg2rad(20)
    
    # J - Geometry factor
    
    J = 0.3
    
    # Kv - velocity factor
    
    Kv= 2.5
    
    # Km - mounting factor
    
    Km = 1.4 
    
    # Cg - gradient factor
    
    Cg = 0.85
    
    Bn = 388  # AISI 4140 Steel
    
    Kt = 1
    
    Sn = Bn/4
    
    Cl = 1.0
    
    Kr = 0.753
    
    Cs = 0.634
    
    Kms = 1.0 
    
    Ko = 1.0
    
    gear_stress = (((Ft*p)/(b*J))*Kv*Ko*Km)/1000
    
    gear_strength = Sn*Cl*Cg*Cs*Kr*Kt*Kms
    
    return gear_stress <= gear_strength

def con_fun22(model):
    
    d=model.D[4]
    n=model.N[4]
    p=model.P[2]
    b=model.b[2]
    
    ratio = (model.D[2]/model.D[1])*(model.D[4]/model.D[3])
    
    Ft = (input_torque*ratio)/(d/2)
    
    pressure_angle = np.deg2rad(20)
    
    # J - Geometry factor
    
    J = 0.3
    
    # Kv - velocity factor
    
    Kv= 2.5
    
    # Km - mounting factor
    
    Km = 1.4 
    
    # Cg - gradient factor
    
    Cg = 0.85
    
    Bn = 388  # AISI 4140 Steel
    
    Kt = 1
    
    Sn = Bn/4
    
    Cl = 1.0
    
    Kr = 0.753
    
    Cs = 0.634
    
    Kms = 1.0 
    
    Ko = 1.0
    
    gear_stress = (((Ft*p)/(b*J))*Kv*Ko*Km)/1000
    
    gear_strength = Sn*Cl*Cg*Cs*Kr*Kt*Kms
    
    return gear_stress <= gear_strength

def con_fun23(model):
    
    d=model.D[5]
    n=model.N[5]
    p=model.P[1]
    b=model.b[1]
    
    ratio = (model.D[2]/model.D[5])
    
    Ft = (input_torque*ratio)/(d/2)
    
    pressure_angle = np.deg2rad(20)
    
    # J - Geometry factor
    
    J = 0.3
    
    # Kv - velocity factor
    
    Kv= 2.5
    
    # Km - mounting factor
    
    Km = 1.4 
    
    # Cg - gradient factor
    
    Cg = 0.85
    
    Bn = 388  # AISI 4140 Steel
    
    Kt = 1
    
    Sn = Bn/4
    
    Cl = 1.0
    
    Kr = 0.753
    
    Cs = 0.634
    
    Kms = 1.0 
    
    Ko = 1.0
    
    gear_stress = (((Ft*p)/(b*J))*Kv*Ko*Km)/1000
    
    gear_strength = Sn*Cl*Cg*Cs*Kr*Kt*Kms
    
    return gear_stress <= gear_strength

def con_fun24(model):
    
    d=model.D[6]
    n=model.N[6]
    p=model.P[3]
    b=model.b[3]
    
    ratio = (model.D[2]/model.D[5])
    
    Ft = (input_torque*ratio)/(d/2)
    
    pressure_angle = np.deg2rad(20)
    
    # J - Geometry factor
    
    J = 0.3
    
    # Kv - velocity factor
    
    Kv= 2.5
    
    # Km - mounting factor
    
    Km = 1.4 
    
    # Cg - gradient factor
    
    Cg = 0.85
    
    Bn = 388  # AISI 4140 Steel
    
    Kt = 1
    
    Sn = Bn/4
    
    Cl = 1.0
    
    Kr = 0.753
    
    Cs = 0.634
    
    Kms = 1.0 
    
    Ko = 1.0
    
    gear_stress = (((Ft*p)/(b*J))*Kv*Ko*Km)/1000
    
    gear_strength = Sn*Cl*Cg*Cs*Kr*Kt*Kms
    
    return gear_stress <= gear_strength

def con_fun25(model):
    
    d=model.D[7]
    n=model.N[7]
    p=model.P[3]
    b=model.b[3]
    
    ratio = (model.D[2]/model.D[5])*(model.D[7]/model.D[6])
    
    Ft = (input_torque*ratio)/(d/2)
    
    pressure_angle = np.deg2rad(20)
    
    # J - Geometry factor
    
    J = 0.3
    
    # Kv - velocity factor
    
    Kv= 2.5
    
    # Km - mounting factor
    
    Km = 1.4 
    
    # Cg - gradient factor
    
    Cg = 0.85
    
    Bn = 388  # AISI 4140 Steel
    
    Kt = 1
    
    Sn = Bn/4
    
    Cl = 1.0
    
    Kr = 0.753
    
    Cs = 0.634
    
    Kms = 1.0 
    
    Ko = 1.0
    
    gear_stress = (((Ft*p)/(b*J))*Kv*Ko*Km)/1000
    
    gear_strength = Sn*Cl*Cg*Cs*Kr*Kt*Kms
    
    return gear_stress <= gear_strength

def con_fun26(model):
    
    d=model.D[8]
    n=model.N[8]
    p=model.P[3]
    b=model.b[3]
    
    ratio = (model.D[2]/model.D[5])*(model.D[8]/model.D[6])
    
    Ft = (input_torque*ratio)/(d/2)
    
    pressure_angle = np.deg2rad(20)
    
    # J - Geometry factor
    
    J = 0.3
    
    # Kv - velocity factor
    
    Kv= 2.5
    
    # Km - mounting factor
    
    Km = 1.4 
    
    # Cg - gradient factor
    
    Cg = 0.85
    
    Bn = 388  # AISI 4140 Steel
    
    Kt = 1
    
    Sn = Bn/4
    
    Cl = 1.0
    
    Kr = 0.753
    
    Cs = 0.634
    
    Kms = 1.0 
    
    Ko = 1.0
    
    gear_stress = (((Ft*p)/(b*J))*Kv*Ko*Km)/1000
    
    gear_strength = Sn*Cl*Cg*Cs*Kr*Kt*Kms
    
    return gear_stress <= gear_strength

# Assigning model constraints
# Rule - return True or False
model.c1 = Constraint(rule=con_fun1)
model.c2 = Constraint(rule=con_fun2)
model.c3 = Constraint(rule=con_fun3)
model.c4 = Constraint(rule=con_fun4)
model.c5 = Constraint(rule=con_fun5)
model.c6 = Constraint(rule=con_fun6)
model.c7 = Constraint(rule=con_fun7)
model.c8 = Constraint(rule=con_fun8)
model.c9 = Constraint(rule=con_fun9)
model.c10 = Constraint(rule=con_fun10)
model.c11 = Constraint(rule=con_fun11)
model.c12 = Constraint(rule=con_fun12)
model.c13 = Constraint(rule=con_fun13)
model.c14 = Constraint(rule=con_fun14)
model.c15 = Constraint(rule=con_fun15)
model.c16 = Constraint(rule=con_fun16)
model.c17 = Constraint(rule=con_fun17)
model.c18 = Constraint(rule=con_fun18)
model.c19 = Constraint(rule=con_fun19)
model.c20 = Constraint(rule=con_fun20)
model.c21 = Constraint(rule=con_fun21)
model.c22 = Constraint(rule=con_fun22)
model.c23 = Constraint(rule=con_fun23)
model.c24 = Constraint(rule=con_fun24)
model.c25 = Constraint(rule=con_fun25)
model.c26 = Constraint(rule=con_fun26)

# Creating objective function for the model

model.obj = Objective(rule=obj_fun, sense=1)

# Solve the problem 

opt = SolverFactory('couenne')
instance = model.create_instance()
results = opt.solve(instance)
instance.solutions.store_to(results)
print(results)
```

The reference solution was obtained in the Linux system. The solver did it in 30 minutes and was stopped due to the manual initialization of "time out". In my case, the "optimal" solution is always found within 20-30 seconds, but the results are obviously far away from optimum (objective are too high) and integer parameters were outputted as a float.

My output is following:

```
Problem: 
- Lower bound: -inf
  Upper bound: inf
  Number of objectives: 1
  Number of constraints: 0
  Number of variables: 23
  Sense: unknown
Solver: 
- Status: ok
  Message: couenne\x3a Optimal
  Termination condition: optimal
  Id: 3
  Error rc: 0
  Time: 24.022721529006958
Solution: 
- number of solutions: 1
  number of solutions displayed: 1
- Gap: None
  Status: optimal
  Message: couenne\x3a Optimal
  Objective:
    obj:
      Value: 5.3362225559607985
  Variable:
    C:
      Value: 24
    D[1]:
      Value: 19.75
    D[2]:
      Value: 28.250000000000004
    D[3]:
      Value: 22.125000000000007
    D[4]:
      Value: 25.874999999999993
    D[5]:
      Value: 19.749999999999996
    D[6]:
      Value: 4
    D[7]:
      Value: 9.333333333333332
    D[8]:
      Value: 25.333333333333336
    N[1]:
      Value: 79
    N[2]:
      Value: 113.00000000000001
    N[3]:
      Value: 177.00000000000006
    N[4]:
      Value: 206.99999999999997
    N[5]:
      Value: 78.99999999999997
    N[6]:
      Value: 24
    N[7]:
      Value: 56
    N[8]:
      Value: 152.00000000000006
    P[1]:
      Value: 4
    P[2]:
      Value: 8
    P[3]:
      Value: 6
    b[1]:
      Value: 3.5
    b[2]:
      Value: 1.5532917757131675
    b[3]:
      Value: 1.7813036269011924
  Constraint: No values
```

Can you guess the source of the problem?

Comment: Integer variables P and N are actually returned with integer values (up to a tolerance). So that is ok. I don't know about the objective. I usually try different MINLP solvers. (You may try to use solvers on NEOS: Pyomo supports accessing those).

Comment: Thank you, I actually change P settings for PositiveReals and it provides a good solution, where the objective value and results are similar to the reference. I tried Bonmin solver, but it's returned an "infeasible" solution error. I will try to solve it via NEOS too.

Comment: Note that BONMIN is capable to solve only convex MINLP problems

Comment: @furious_bilbo - As far as I understood, COUENNE starts several instances of either Bonmin, Cbc, Clp, or Ipopt in order to tackle non-convex problems. Each of them can only find local optima. But why does COUENNE not combine the results of parallel starting points to a global solution?

Comment: @artemIk96 - did you solve this issue? I am confused about a similar situation and thus interested in you experience. ;-)